# Spring Boot error when deployed on Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, heroku-ci

I am having trouble deploying my app on Heroku.
It builds successfully on localhost without any errror. It even builds successfully when I do `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package`.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0
com.furntrade
SpringBoot
1.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.6
 

FurntradeManagmentServet

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.1.3</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.12.1</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>3.3.1-1</webjars-jquery.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProperties>
                            <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                            <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                            <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                            <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                        </additionalProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is application.properties file (I removed my db credentials)

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.maxActive=10
spring.datasource.maxIdle=5
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true\
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://DNLOCATION:5432/DBTANLENAME
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
lspring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
hibernate.cache.auto_evict_collection_cache=true
server.error.include-message=always
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
spring.profiles.active=production
server.port=${PORT:5000}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/SpringBoot-1.0.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS
```

**settings.properties file**

```
java.runtime.version=1.8
```

This is the error im getting in logs

```
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[40,48] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
         location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[41,48] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
         location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[42,48] cannot find symbol
         symbol:   method of(java.lang.String)
         location: interface java.util.List
       [INFO] 3 errors 
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  14.426 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-14T22:40:26Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project FurntradeManagmentServet: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[40,48] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR]   symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
       [ERROR]   location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[41,48] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR]   symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
       [ERROR]   location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_530e329c/src/main/java/com/furntrade/furntrademanagmentservet/Security/SecurityConfig.java:[42,48] cannot find symbol
       [ERROR]   symbol:   method of(java.lang.String)
       [ERROR]   location: interface java.util.List
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR]
```

I have to mention that I don't have those `java.util.List` errors on my localhost.
I have no idea where I am doing wrong.

Comment: `List.of` is only present in Java 9 and later. You seem to be using 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a file named system.properties in project directory and write `java.runtime.version=11`. I hope it should work as because this had worked for me.